# There are still actual/supported andengine pixel collision on GLES2 Anchor Center?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing (trying at least) android-game and cannot find actual implementation of collisions between sprites for GLES2-Anchor-Center. No search results.

All implementations of Perfect Pixel Collision (m5 and MakersF on github for example) has a lot of errors, that cannot be resolved (maybe im just stupid). Anchor-Center even supported? Cannot post links for all of them, need more rep.

My issue for one of implementations example:
https://github.com/MakersF/CollisionTest/issues/1

Thanks for any help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official pixel perfect extension to AndEngine. There is a lot of information how to make MakerF's extension work. It's bit of a reading explaining that the collision core has been separated into another project. For more information, see the forum post [from here onwards](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-extension-t8736-50.html#p57382).

It will take some effort, but it will help you understand how to collisions work :)